# Beta distribution with support from 0 to 2

Tags: probability, distributions, beta-distribution

Is there a way to make the Beta distribution have support from 0 to 2, instead of 0 to 1?

Answer (score 1):

Sure: define the CDF or PDF in terms of

- $C'(x,\alpha, \beta) = C(x/2, \alpha, \beta)$
- $P'(x,\alpha,\beta) = P(x/2,\alpha,\beta)/2$

where $C$ and $P$ are the original Beta CDF and PDF and $C'$ and $P'$ are the new ones (and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the two shape parameters).

Wikipedia describes a [four-parameter beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Four_parameters) which includes both an arbitrary scale parameter (which would be 2 in your case) as well as a shift parameter (which would be 0 for you, since you want the left endpoint of the distribution to stay at zero rather than shifting).

Comment: Hi, and please, how to sample having that new CDF? Is there an inverse Beta equation?